# entity framework write raw SQL Query for joining 5 tables

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a query that joins 5 tables, and I am new to EntityFrameWork core version 5.0.4. The query should perform the following:

```
SELECT TOP 10  blcc.itemNo, blcc.itemName, b.customerName
from tabel1 bc
          join tabel2 b on b.Id = bc.Id
          join tabel3 bl on b.Id = bl.id
          join tabel4 blc on bl.Id = blc.id
          join tabel5 blcc on blc.Id = blcc.Id
          WHERE blcc.name IN ('name1','name2')
```

can anyone please guide me about how to execute this query in the entity framework, and if there is a better way to get a better execution-time/performance please let me know as well.
I have tried to run the following code but it did not work for me.

```
var obj = _context.table1.FromSqlRaw("my SQL query").ToList()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should have _context.Database.SqlQuery<T>() method available to you.

Comment: unfortunately, there is no SqlQuery method in my version of the entityframework

Comment: What do you mean by `it did not work for me`? How did it not work?

Comment: Sorry I read it as EF 5.0, like old old 5.0.  For Core 5.0  that FromSqlRaw is the way to go.  What error message are you receiving?   What type is obj? If you are using plain object type then that's not going to provide useful data to you.

Comment: thanks Rex, indeed _context.Set<MyExpectedObjectReturnedFromSQL>.FromSqlRaw is the correct solution for this.

Comment: However, I have another question related to the same issue, How can I pass the variables 'name1','name2' in the IN('name1','name2') programmatically from an array. in other word I want to pass an array instead of the hardcoded values ('name1','name2')